# How to define list of formated strings in ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

Lets say I have a list of dicts like this

```yaml
elements:
  - key: first_key
    value: first_value
  - key: key_number_2
    value: middle_value
  - key: last_key
    value: three
```

and I want to have a list of strings formatted list this `{key}="{value}"`, so the expected result is

```yaml
['first_key="first_value"', 'key_number_2="middle_value"', 'last_key="three"']
```

in Python I would do this `['{key}="{value}"'.format(**i) for i in elements]`, but there is no list comprehension in jinja2.

How should this look like in Ansible?

---

comments:

1. The end result is actually suppose to be `first_key="first_value", key_number_2="middle_value", last_key="three"` but I'm assuming I should solve the above problem and then put this through `join` filter. Correct me if I'm wrong
2. This is going to be part of an Ansible template.

Comment: List comprehension is just a shorter, more Pythonic way to do a loop. So if this is supposed to be in a template, just do a [`for`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to have a variable with the values, you can simply use a `loop`, then a `join` filter indeed:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        list: "{{ list | default([]) + [item.key ~ '=\"' ~ item.value ~ '\"'] }}"
      loop: "{{ elements }}"
      vars:
        elements:
          - key: first_key
            value: first_value
          - key: key_number_2
            value: middle_value
          - key: last_key
            value: three

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list | join(', ') }}"
```

Would yield the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'first_key', 'value': 'first_value'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'key_number_2', 'value': 'middle_value'})
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': 'last_key', 'value': 'three'})

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: first_key="first_value", key_number_2="middle_value", last_key="three"

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Now, if you need this in a Jinja template, you can use a plain Jinja [`for`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#for) along with the `loop.last` variable for the comma:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {% for element in elements -%}
            {{ element.key }}="{{ element.value }}"
            {%- if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
          {%- endfor %}
      vars:
        elements:
          - key: first_key
            value: first_value
          - key: key_number_2
            value: middle_value
          - key: last_key
            value: three
```

Would yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: first_key="first_value", key_number_2="middle_value", last_key="three"

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Yea, I did something similar (concatenate in a loop) but your code looks cleaner than mine :). IMHO something declarative like list comprehension reads better, was looking for some wild cascade of filters or something.